# The maximim number of elements in the Alternating group of degree 28

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I know if $r$ is a prime number, then $(r-1)!$ is maximum number of elements of same order in the alternating group $A_{r}$. What is maximum number of elements of same order in the alternating group $A_{28}$?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, q-Javadi! It's great that you're thinking about group theory and we're happy to help you answer your question. There's one point about your question that I'm unsure about. Namely, could you please clarify what is the relationship between $p$ and $r$? I upvoted your question because I think it's a very interesting one; if you can clarify this point, then I would be very happy and interested to discuss further. Thank you so much for joining our community and we hope that you have a productive time discussing mathematics here!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $p = r$, so either "if $r$ is a prime ..." or $(p-1)!$ and $A_p$.

Comment: All elements of a given cycle type will have the same order (although not conversely), and the order of a cycle type will be the LCM of the constituent cycle lengths.  We can thus break the problem into looking at two separate problems: cycle types that represent many elements, and orders which match multiple cycle types.  The proof of the result for primes should give you clues in both directions.

Comment: There should be more than $\frac{28!}{52}$ elements of order $26$

Comment: @AmiteshDatta: Thanks for your comment. Yes $p=r$. I edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just consulted a table of the 1883 conjugacy classes of $A_{28}$ and counted to find the most numerous.

There are $(28!)/27$ elements of order 27 in $A_{28}$. This is largest number of elements of the same order. The second most numerous order is 24 with $7632609771546411536941056000$ elements, coming from 93 different conjugacy classes.

A single $k$-cycle has centralizer of type $C_k \times S_{n-k}$ inside $S_n$ so if $n-k$ is small, it has many conjugates.

We cannot use $k=28$ in $A_n$ however, for the simple reason that $A_n$ does not contain cycles of even length. The runner up is $k=27$.

So in general, $A_{2n}$ has at least $((2n)!)/(2n-1)$ elements of order $2n-1$ (namely the $(2n-1)$-cycles), which is a fair amount. $A_{16}$ and $A_{22}$ have extra elements of order $15$ and $21$ respectively.

By comparison, $A_{2n+1}$ has at least $((2n+1)!)/(2n+1) = (2n)!$ elements of order $2n+1$. This is similar to your claim for $r=2n+1$ prime.

For $1 \leq r \leq 50$ the most numerous order is $r$ if $r$ is odd, and $r-1$ if $r$ is even. One might ask in a separate question if this patterns holds indefinitely.

Comment: No problem. (I verified the $r,r-1$ conjecture to $r \leq 73$, but the number of conjugacy classes is getting too large to handle this way; presumably a theoretical argument is possible.)

Answer (score 0):

I would appreciate if you let me know what's the refrence for the first claim which says "if $r$  is a prime number, then $(r−1)!$  is maximum number of elements of same order in the alternating group $A r $ . "